# how do i make this string with arabic chars display correctly on my web page?

Tags: asp.net, localization, right-to-left

on my page i have a time range printed in the format of

```
12:00 AM - 12:00 PM
```

i have to display this appropriately for whatever culture the browser supplies. i'm having an issue with arabic (ar-ae): the am/pm indicator seems to change the text ordering for part of the string. the string has the right characters in the right places in memory, but shows them in a different order.

so for my start and end times, i have strings like

```
03:00 ص
```

and

```
11:00 م
```

and then i put them together like

```
string dummytext = t1string + " - " + t2string;
```

when the page is written, the range is displayed as

```
03:00 ص - 11:00 م
```

i've tried putting each piece in a Label control and wrapping everything in a div with `dir="ltr"` and haven't made any progress.  this is happening in a table cell if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to fix it: i added the "left-to-right" unicode character after the arabic character for "AM" in the example above.

```
string dummytext = t1string + "&#x200e; - " + t2string;
```

`&#x200e;` is the html entity for the ltr character. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm

the page now displays

```
03:00 ص‎ - 11:00 م
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to be using the "right to left" (dir="rtl")?

Comment: not in my case. the site is mostly english text, left to right. dates and times use local formatting/characters but still need to be ltr for consistency.

Comment: then could you surround the dates and times with a div tag that has the rtl set in CSS?